# Twitter bootstrap 3 - compare ratio of columns on each device

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

With the new version of `Twitter Bootstrap 3`, the `grid` is divided into different `column` class (`col-*`) depending on device size.

When I read [Grid example mixed](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed), and I see a div with

`<div class="col-12 col-lg-8">8</div>`

Do I have to understand that a `col-12` is equal to a `col-lg-8` (in ratio) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply means when device is pc then col will span8 and if mobile then span12.

Comment: But if on the mobile device (span12), that implies that the following element will be on the next row, right? But not on the the desktop pc.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-8">8</div>
```

This means for medium screen you will get 12 column for that div
For larger screen you will get 8 column for that div
Anything above the larger screen you will keep on getting 8 column for that div
Anything less than medium screen (xs or sm), you get 12 column by default.. correct me if I am wrong please